# Is there a posting style and conventions section?

Tags: support, posts

My posts are OK by the FAQ, but people (including me) don't like how they look when they come out.

I have not seen a conventions and style page to help format posts for Stack Overflow. Is there one?

Comment: Convention #1:  The title of your question should *be* a question.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints is a piece by Jon Skeet that covers this and more.

Comment: non-shortened version of url : http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @DanBeale Thanks.  You're right, I ordinarily wouldn't post shortened URLs like that, save for that one was created by Jon himself for this sort of purpose.

Comment: If you don't like how they look, you should fix them.